# How to avoid a dot after a question mark using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

With the macro `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1.\isdot}\addspace}`
defined below I get a dot `.` after the question mark `?`. Is it possible to have the dot as default but to avoid it with a question mark at the end of the sentence?

[image: The Output]

```
%%
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}  
@article{kahle:2018,
    author = {Reinhard Kahle and Isabel Oitavem},
    journal = {Kairos. Journal of Philosophy \& Science},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--11},
    title = {What is Hilbert's 24th Problem?},
    volume = {20},
    year = {2018}}
%
@book{querenburg,
    author = {Boto von Querenburg},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {Mengentheoretische Topologie},
    year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}   
%%
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}
%%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1.\isdot}\addspace}
%%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` does this automatically.

It doesn't do it for you because you have put a dot in your `title` format.

Your format should be:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}  
@article{kahle:2018,
    author = {Reinhard Kahle and Isabel Oitavem},
    journal = {Kairos. Journal of Philosophy \& Science},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--11},
    title = {What is Hilbert's 24th Problem?},
    volume = {20},
    year = {2018}}
@book{querenburg,
    author = {Boto von Querenburg},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {Mengentheoretische Topologie},
    year = {2000}}
@article{volterra:1981,
    author = {Volterra, V.},
    journal = {Battaglini G.},
    pages = {76--87},
    title = {Some observation on pointwise discontinuous functions},
    volume = {19},
    year = {1881}}
\end{filecontents}   
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: David, this is known, but then in all the titles of articles the dot is away, which I would like to have. The book example shows what should happen.

Comment: @Ulrich Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. If you add
`@article{volterra:1981,
 author = {Volterra, V.},
 journal = {Battaglini G.},,
 pages = {76--87},
 title = {Some observation on pointwise discontinuous functions},
 volume = {19},
 year = {1881}}`
to my example, you will see, what happens: If I have a dot at the and of the title, then I can use your suggestion. If not, I have to use my one.

So to get it right, I have to add the period in the bibtex-entry if no other solution is available. (sorry, but I don't know how to add a code here)

Comment: @Ulrich `volterra:1981` seems to look fine with the MWE in my answer. There is a dot after the `title`. What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: "you never stop learning"  I must have overlooked something or misunderstood something.

Comment: @Ulrich In general it is quite unidiomatic to have punctuation commands end `\DeclareFieldFormat` definitions. This interferes with the normal working of `biblatex`'s punctuation facilities. In this particular case the fact that you put an `\isdot` after the literal `.` you had, made `biblatex` think the "." is an abbreviation dot after which a question mark would be legal. But as David showed in the example there is no need at all for the `.` and the `\addspace`, so they can just be discarded.

Comment: @moewe  I finally found the problem: I had a `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}` in my settings for `bib latex` which was finally the problem with the dots.

Comment: @Ulrich Yeah, that would remove a lot of dots.